# iOS - NSConcreteData crash

Tags: ios, printing, crash

I  have a `UIButton` that is linked to some code that invokes `UIPrintInteractionController` to print a PDF document.

If I tap the button, the view pops up to let me select a printer and then print the document.  However, if I tap outside the view to dismiss the popup, and then *quickly* tap the "Print" button again, I get the following crash:

```
[NSConcreteData respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa4696d0
```

I have debugged with NSZombies enabled, and the crash occurs at this line:

```
printController.printingItem = dataToPrint;
```

`dataToPrint` is instantiated in the same method but prior to this `printController` line:

```
NSData *dataToPrint = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];
```

This crash only occurs if I tap quickly, if I give it a second, everything goes smoothly.

Anyone have any idea what this could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make 'dataToPrint' a strong ivar, and only nil it when you are 100% sure it won't be used again. Most likely the 'printController.printingItem' retains it, but when you dismiss the popup it gets released before the 'Print' button is hit again.